# Invariant Violation: No callback found with cbID 3902 and callID 1951 for module <unknown>

Tags: react-native, components, mobx, mobx-react, mobx-react-lite

I'm creating a library of React Native components.

On my library I have this simple component

```
import React from 'react'
import {View, Text } from 'react-native'

export default function App() {
    return <View>
        <Text>Hello</Text>
    </View>
}
```

Then, on the app I'm using this component

```
import React from 'react'
import { View } from 'react-native'
import App from '@components-lib/App'
        
export default function RootApp() {
return (
        <View>
            <App />
        </View>
    )
}
```

So far everything works. Now, I need to make my simple component observable (I'm using mobx), but then if I change my simple component to

```
import React from 'react'
import {View, Text } from 'react-native'

import { observer } from 'mobx-react-lite' <-- adding this line

export default function App() {
    return <View>
        <Text>Hello</Text>
    </View>
}
```

By simply adding the import of observer I start to get tons of this error

> Invariant Violation: No callback found with cbID 3902 and callID 1951
> for module . Args:
> '["{"codeFrame":{"content":"\u001b[0m \u001b[90m 20
> |\u001b[39m   }\u001b[0m\n\u001b[0m \u001b[90m 21
> |...(truncated)..."]'

Any idea what the problem is? If I remove the observer import everything starts to work again...

Comment: Why are you using require for `mobx` and `import` for other libs?

Comment: Sorry, this was a mistake I made when I was creating the post. I already fixed it. Im using `import` everywhere....